# How can I identify duplicate hostnames mixed with FQDN?

Tags: microsoft-excel, duplicate

I have several thousand hostnames in a list. Some of these names are FQDN, and some are hostname only. How can I identify duplicates in this situation?

- HostABC
- HostABC.domain.com

The above are the same host, just one is fully qualified and one is not.

I am using the following formula that identifies exact matches, I would like to expand this formula to include partial matches as well.

`=countif(($F$2:$F2,$F2&"*")=1)+0`

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have a formula that identifies exact matches, I would like to expand this formula to include partial matches as well.  =countif(($F$2:$F2,$F2&"*")=1)+0

Comment: Have you tried searching for "excel partial matches"?

Answer (score 0):

Just write this Formula it will give you the number of duplicates or count
`=COUNTIF($A$1:A1,"="&$C1&"*")`
in column A is your Data the names, the first occurrence is 1 it will increment each time you have duplicate 
In C1 write the following as a helper column
`=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1,1)-1),A1)`
And drag the 2 formulas down.